# Android UDP send packet do not have response , and try catch does not catch error

Tags: android, sockets, networking, udp, android-networking

```
try {
        Log.d("test1","start");
        flag = true;
        portRemoteNum = 2001;
        portLocalNum = 8080;
        addressIP = "192.168.8.1";
        socketUDP = new DatagramSocket(portLocalNum);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("test1",e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {

        InetAddress serverAddress = InetAddress.getByName(addressIP);
        byte data[] = str.getBytes();
        DatagramPacket packetS = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length,serverAddress,portRemoteNum);
        socketUDP.send(packetS);
        Log.d("test1","end");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("test1",e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
        socketUDP.close();
}
```

Here is what I would like to achieve, I have a device and a phone, and I connect the device through wifi directly like this,

Android Phone =Wifi=> Device A

Then I use the above code to send the udp packet, it show the "end" in my logging , however , there is no response in my device, and no error catch. How to debug it? Thanks , and what is the possible root cause of the problem?

Comment: Well, it's an unreliable protocol, isn't it? There's no guarantee the datagram got sent, and no guarantee you'll get an exception instead.

Comment: thanks. right now it seems not working at all, but not sometimes not work

Comment: Well that's what I just said. It's unreliable. That doesn't rule out a programming problem at the receiver,  but you haven't posted that so no comment is possible.